# Image background as page header w/Responsive White Space Below

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to replicate the header image background from the following site: http://vistachurchslo.com/sundays/what-to-expect

Each page has a header with a background image. Regardless of the size/aspect/orientation of the browser window **there is ALWAYS white-space (a blank horizontal area) below the background image. The image is always filling the browser window (except for the bar below it). The page text is not visible until you scroll/swipe down.**

Can this be done with plain CSS, or do I need javascript as well? I would really appreciate any help figuring this out.

Image attached to help see the effect.
[image]

[image]

THANKS!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, the background images on the website you have linked to are parallaxing, there is no white space under them.

Comment: I have updated my question and included some images. I'm not sure what you are seeing, but the images fill the view, but have a bar of "white" across the bottom. Text is not visible until you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "white-space below the background image" isn't just a bar. That's the next section tag coming in. If you look at the css of that section:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)), url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/571fb2df2ab0dfe37255621b/59d667e68849c400014a5c31_outside-vets2-hd.jpg");
background-position: 0px 0px, 50% 50%;
background-size: auto, cover;
background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
height: 90%;
```

So they set the background to be the image, set the size of it to cover the section, and then set the height of the section to be 90%. This means that 10% of the next section will be visible, which is the "white-space" that you're seeing.

As for the scrolling, this is simple screen-wipe. I found [Scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io) really useful for that when I was beginning. It allows you to add a "scene" for each tag you choose (in this case, the sections") and then add a pin to achieve that screenwipe effect. [Here's](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html) a demo.